# Adding/updating column tags after populating a new document with bookmark values

Tags: workflow, column, calculated-column, metadata, vba

Im currently running a project for a customer with the goal to automate a SharePoint environment along with word templates. So far i managed to create a word template which includes a Userform where users can input information, which then gets printed to 4 bookmarks in the document. The Userform gets called as soon as the document is opened. The document itself is docx since i made a reference to the docm file containing the macro.

The goal of the project is having the flexibility of the document macro, while also automatically assigning the input values(The bookmark values in the word document) to a column value which marks the document in SharePoint. As to be seen down here, i have several columns containing document "Phases" for the customer. 
[image]

The have to be populated preferably by some sort of pop-up or button within SharePoint. Ideally within the header bar(The bar where new documents can be opened or uploaded, quick edit etc.) It would be great if they get automatically populated as soon as the Bookmarks are filled in the document.

As for my second question. I was looking for a way to create another column with a value based on other column values. For example, i would create a column named "Title" which is build off other column values; **DateCreated_DocumentPase_DocumentType_RandomGeneratedNumber** etc.
I did a lot of research but i just cant seem to find a proper solution for this. Maybe InfoPath can help but i have no idea if it is viable for something like this.

Short description of the solutions i'm looking for

- A way to automatically/manually populate columns within SharePoint based on the values i filled in at my bookmarks in word.
- (Optional) Create a column which builds it value from other column values

I hope someone else sees the light in doing this.

-Tob